# How to make the color function from xcolor package work over multiple cells?

Tags: color, align

Recently I had to prepare a simple picture with multiple graphs of functions. For that purpose, I wanted to color each graph of function accordingly to the displayed function itself. Of course, because I listed the functions I used the `align` environment. Soon the trouble started arising. First, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}f(x) &\color{blue} = x+1 \\
\color{red}g(x) &\color{red} = 4 \\
\color{green}h(x) &\color{green} = -\frac{1}{2}x - 2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The document of course compiles just fine and the output is indeed satisfactory, but since I am dedicated to details I can't help myself but ask: **how can I make the `color` function work over multiple cells?** I of course know that the so called "cell", or the alignment symbol `&` if you will is the source of the problem, since `color` is only meant for the whole environment or one cell. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: a table cell is a tex group, so fonts assignments and everything else is scoped to a group it  is possible in some cases to make colors not obey tex grouping but latex goes to a lot of effort to make colors act like fonts and you would have to undo all that.

Comment: Hm, sounds like a very complex solution, and I'm not very well versed in deconstruction programming. If you have any idea, please share it with me. For now, I don't know how to get a hold of the problem.

Comment: my strong advice would be not to do it: the whole colour setup is designed to make colours obey tex groups

Comment: You _can_ do it with tikz, it allows math environments inside nodes and you can set node groups that share styles. But don't; You lose what you get from the actual math environment such as equation numbering, easy alignment… It is easier just to copy the `\color` command to the equation.